# Unable to go to the method of mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am having issues with JUnit test cases. For some reason, I am unable to go to a method of the mocked class and I am not sure why that actually is happening.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID;

public class Sample {
    protected SomeClass someClass;

    public void setVariables(SomeClass someClass) {
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }

    protected UserInfo func(String id){
        UserInfo userInfo = someClass.getInfo(id);
        // I checked that the someClass is mocked instance
        // id is not null
    }
}
```

I am not even going in the following method. I am not sure why that actually is happening which then gives me NPE on above statment.

```
public class SomeClass{
    public UserInfo getInfo(String id) {
        // not even going in this function at all
        if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) return null;

        UserInfo userInfo = null;
        try {
            // do Something
        } catch () {
        }
        return userInfo;
    }
}

class SampleTest{

    Sample sample;
    SomeClass someclass = mock(SomeClass.class);
    UserInfo userinfo = mock(UserInfo.class);
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        // other initialization
        sample = new Sample();
        sample.setVariables(someclass);
    }
    @Test
    void func(){
        when(someclass.getInfo(randomUUID().toString())).thenReturn(userinfo);
        UserInfo userInfo = sample.func(randomUUID().toString());
        // comparison using assert
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the error doesnt come from SampleTest#setUp() where sample is null?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the default ctor(); @benebo22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong when statement.

when(someclass.getInfo(**randomUUID().toString()**)).thenReturn(userinfo)

Some possible solutions:

```
var randomUuid = randomUUID().toString();

when(someclass.getInfo(anyString())).thenReturn(userinfo)
when(someclass.getInfo(any())).thenReturn(userinfo)
when(someclass.getInfo(eq(randomUuid))).thenReturn(userinfo)
```

If you mock an instance of the SomeClass, your **getInfo** code will not be executed, try to use spy instead.

```
SomeClass someclass = spy(SomeClass.class);
```

Comment: how on this planet, you found this bug?

Comment: when to use mock vs spy?

Comment: try to use spy instead of mock

Comment: mock when you dont need your code, spy when you need your code

Comment: if we are spying a class [like SomeClass], is it OK to use the spySomeClass to access the member variable and initiate them? Is it proper mocking or no? For e.g. 

`SomeClass spySomeClass = spy(SomeClass.class);
spySomeClass.variable1 = someValue;`